# Compose javascript functions with more than one argument

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

How can I convert this function composition into more readable format?

```
funcA(argumentA, funcB(argumentA, funcC(argumentA, argumentB)))
```

What I'd like to achieve is something more like this:

```
compose(funcC, funcB, funcA)(argumentA, argumentB)
```

I'm using this compose function implementation:

```
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)))
```

The problem is I need argumentA in all function calls as a first parameter and every function returns a value to be passed as a second parameter to the next function. I know I could create separate function-returning functions and use them like so:

```
compose(funcCWithArg(argumentA), funcBWithArg(argumentA), funcAWithArg(argumentA))(argumentB)
```

but in my actual case there aren't only three of them, but many more and that would require some serious amount of code just to write them down. Is there a simpler way to do that?

EDIT: I can't use any external library. Only vanilla js.

Comment: Ramdajs has a function that does that http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose

Comment: @user93 From the docs you provided: "The rightmost function may have any arity; the remaining functions must be unary.". So that's not solving my problem. I need two parameters in every function.

Comment: @zorza compose partially applied functions with a prebound first argument.

Comment: @zerkms That's the solution I want to avoid if possible as I stated in the question.

Comment: @zorza First of all, this isn't function composition in the original sense anymore. Sure, you could create your own combinator to avoid the nested structure. However, this would disguise the control flow and make the code hard to read. The only reason why you would do this is to remain DRY. I doubt that you will need this combinator often, though. So either use partially applied functions or write the function calls manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create new functions that are partial applications using `bind`. Then use the `compose` function you already have:

```
const funcA = (x, y) => `A(${x}, ${y})`;
const funcB = (x, y) => `B(${x}, ${y})`;
const funcC = (x, y) => `C(${x}, ${y})`;

const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));
const partials = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.map((f) => f.bind(this, ...args));

console.log(compose(...partials(funcA, funcB, funcC)("a"))("b"));

// Output:
// A(a, B(a, C(a, b)))
```

**UPDATE**

You can also build a single function that composes the partials with the first argument passed and then calls them with the other arguments. (I *think* this is what you want? I wasn't 100% sure what to do with more than two arguments.)

```
const partialCompose = (...fns) => (...args) => compose(...partials(...fns)(args[0]))(...args.slice(1));

console.log(partialCompose(funcA, funcB, funcC)("a", "b")); // same output as above
```

Answer (score 3):

Using vanilla JS,

```
const compose = (...fns) => (arg1, arg2) => fns.reduce((arg, f) => f(arg1, arg), arg2);
```

**Explanation**

`compose` becomes a function returning a function, which loops through the list of functions passed to it, passing the first argument to every function call.

**Test**

```
const sum = (a, b) => (a + b);
const mult = (a, b) => (a * b);
compose(sum, mult)(2, 3) === mult(2, sum(2, 3));  // true
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not hard to write a function like this:

```
const link = (...fns) => (a, ...args) =>
    fns.slice(1).reduce((val, fn) => fn(a, val), fns[0](a, ...args));
```

If you wanted it to be robust enough to handle errors gracefully, it would take more.  But this should be a start.

You would use it like this:

```
const funcA = (x, y) => `funcA(${x}, ${y})`;
const funcB = (x, y) => `funcB(${x}, ${y})`;
const funcC = (x, y) => `funcC(${x}, ${y})`;

link(funcA, funcB, funcC)('argumentA', 'argumentB');
//=> "funcC(argumentA, funcB(argumentA, funcA(argumentA, argumentB)))"
```

You can see this in action **[on Runkit](https://runkit.com/crosseye/link)**.

(And obviously you can do a `reverse` if you want the opposite argument order.)